# An custom event that should print text entered from the keyboard

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Using javascript, p5.js I made `class EventEmitter` which is call when a letter is typed on the keyboard.

```js
class EventEmitter {
    static event = {}

    static on(eventName, callback) {
        if (this.event[eventName])
            this.event[eventName].push(callback)
        else
            this.event[eventName] = [callback]
    }

    static trigger(eventName, ...rest) {
        if (this.event[eventName])
            this.event[eventName].forEach(cb => {
                cb.apply(rest)
            });
    }
}

// This function trigger an event
function keyTyped() {
    EventEmitter.trigger('input')
}
```

Here I created a function that `return object` in which the message from the keyboard will be stored.

```
function createIN() {
    return {
        value: '',
        onIN: function(callback) {
            EventEmitter.on('input', callback)
        }
    }
}
```

This part uses event made using `EventEmitter` to print the `value` form `object` entered from the keyboard to the console.

```js
var inp = createIN()
inp.onIN(doSomething)

function doSomething() {
    console.log(this.value)
}
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasicev/hrk3gq2e/2/) to open code online

Comment: What's the question exactly and what problem is this supposed to solve? `value` never changes and `doSomething()` would need a parameter to be able to access a value. `this` is bound to the window in that func.

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger the event you need to pass the key variable and when you print the key will be on the keyword "this".

```
function keyTyped() {
  EventEmitter.trigger('input', key)
}

function doSomething() {
  console.log(this);
}
```